# Getting error 'Office.context.ui.messageParent is not a function' when trying to send message

Tags: typescript, office-js

I am trying to use the OfficeJS dialog API to handle authentication within my app.

I am able to display the dialog, and register for dialog messages, using this code.

```
let loginDialog: Office.Dialog;

export function showLoginDialog(signinUrl: string) {


    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(signinUrl,
    {
        height: 55,
        width: 25
    },
    function (asyncResult) {
        loginDialog = asyncResult.value;
        loginDialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processDialogMessage);
    });
}


function processDialogMessage(arg) {
    var dialogMessage = JSON.parse(arg.message);

    if (loginDialog) { 
        loginDialog.close();
    }

    window.location.href = dialogMessage.returnUri;
}
```

After the auth redirects, My popup will end up on a page that calls this function.

```
export function authComplete(loginSuccess: boolean, returnUri: string): void {

    let message = JSON.stringify({
        loginSuccess: loginSuccess,
        returnUri: returnUri
    });

    //Fails here
    Office.context.ui.messageParent(message);
}
```

When I try to message my parent to close the dialog, I am getting an exception.

```
Office.context.ui.messageParent is not a function
```

I am currently using Outlook Desktop 365

Comment: Are you loading and initializing Office on the page that calls messageParent? See https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/initialize-add-in

Comment: Yep. I can tell Office is loaded, because I would get 'messageParent cannot be called on an undefined reference' error otherwise.

All of my code executes after Office.onReady is invoked.

Comment: This might be related to recent changes made in `messageParent`. Specifically, new controls on what domain can be the recipient of a message. See [Cross-domain messaging to the host runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#cross-domain-messaging-to-the-host-runtime). As an experiment, can you add a second parameter to the call of messageParent: `Office.context.ui.messageParent(message, { targetOrigin: "*" });`. See if that changes anything.

Comment: Thanks Rick. I made this change, but it didn't fix the problem. My request is not crossing a domain barrier anyway.

Comment: This may be a bug. I suggest raising an issue on the [office-js repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose)

Comment: Hi Dave, could you provide me with some additional details to help understand the issue. Could you provide the version number of Office, platform (windows, web, or mac), and what web runtime is being used (IE/Edge)? On recent versions of win32 you can identify the runtime by clicking the personality menu in top right corner of add-in, and choosing Security Info. Is the domain you pass to displayDialogAsync the same domain that is calling messageParent?

Comment: @DanSaunders-MSFT, yes, everything is on the same domain.

I basically gave up on this. We are only going to support the desktop client until Office on the web has better built in support for oauth. I don't think I should have to make custom pages to call these apis for something so common.